# Borel measurability of "closest point selection"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(Y,d)$ be a metric space, and let $X \subset Y$. Does there exist a Borel measurable function $\gamma: Y \to X$ such that, for all $y \in Y$, $d(y,\gamma(y)) \leq 2 \inf\{d(y,x) : x \in X\}$? I would be interested in such a selection function with the assumption that $X$ is Borel, or even closed, but I would prefer an answer that works for arbitrary $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is separable, then yes. Take a countable dense subset $\left\{x_n\right\}_n$.

Define $f:Y\to\mathbb{N}$ by $f(x)=\operatorname{min}\left\{n:d(x,x_n)<2d(x,X)\right\}$. Then $f$ is measurable (exercise), and the map $x:\mathbb{N}\to X$, $x(n)=x_n$ is trivially measurable as well, so $\gamma=xf$ works.

My guess is that this could be false for non-separable $X$, but I don't have any counter-example at hand.

Comment: Thanks. It's clear that this $\gamma$ is Borel measurable when restricted to $Y \setminus X$, and that it is Borel measurable when $X$ is a Borel subset of $Y$ (defining $\gamma|_X = Id$, as is obviously necessary). Is it Borel measurable when $X$ is not a Borel subset of $Y$?

Comment: @Justthisguy It is actually clear that $f$ is *always* measurable (what is $f^{-1}(n)$?), and that $x:\mathbb{N}\to f$ is also measurable (because the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{N}$ has all its subsets), so $\gamma=xf$ is *always* measurable as well. However you can think of separability of $X$ as some "approximation by Borel subsets", because $d(y,X)=d(y,D)$ for every dense subset $D\subseteq X$, and every countable set is Borel.

Comment: I agree that $f$ is measurable, but it is only defined as a function from $Y \setminus X$ to $\mathbb N$. If $x \in X$, set you are taking the min over is empty. So we have to define $\gamma$ piecewise on  $X$ and $Y \setminus X$, and it's not clear to me that this map is Borel if $X$ is not a Borel set.

Comment: You are right! By the condition $d(x,\gamma(x))\leq 2d(x,X)$, we necessarily have $\gamma(x)=x$ for all $x\in\overline{X}$. This already shows that if $X$ is not closed we cannot have any function $\gamma$ (measurable or not) satisfying this property (because we're asking the range of $\gamma$ to be contained in $X$).

Comment: Ha, right. Thanks!